# how to analyze files and folders in 1TB hard drive?

Tags: sql, vb.net, file-io, filesystems

I have been given a challenge to analyze 1 TB files and folder. My first thoughts and attempt was using System.IO getfiles(targetdirecotry).
So I create a program to recurse into all folders and get all the files.
for each file, I insert them into SQL Table. once all folders and files are in SQL table, it would be easy for me to analyze and write any reports the client wants.

Below are my code. ( This code runs for about 10 hours to complete 2 million rows) 
The downside is this code runs for a while. I am wondering if there is a better/faster way to do this?

here is my code.

```
 Public Sub getFilesInDirectory(sPath As String)
        If File.Exists(sPath) Then
            ' This path is a file.
            ProcessFile(sPath)
        Else
            If Directory.Exists(sPath) Then
                ' This path is a directory.
                ProcessDirectory(sPath)
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is not a valid file or directory.", sPath)
            End If
        End If
        MsgBox("DONE" & Now)
    End Sub
' Process all files in the directory passed in, recurse on any directories that are found, and process the files they contain. 

Public Sub ProcessDirectory(ByVal targetDirectory As String)
    Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles(targetDirectory)
    ' Process the list of files found in the directory. 
    Dim fileName As String
    For Each fileName In fileEntries
        Console.WriteLine("Processed file '{0}'.", fileName)
        ProcessFile(fileName)
    Next fileName
    Dim subdirectoryEntries As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory)
    ' Recurse into subdirectories of this directory. 
    Dim subdirectory As String
    For Each subdirectory In subdirectoryEntries
        ProcessDirectory(subdirectory)
    Next subdirectory
End Sub 'ProcessDirectory

' Insert logic for processing found files here. 
Public Sub ProcessFile(ByVal path As String)
    Dim SQLString As String
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    SQLString = " insert into FileTable (Path, CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, IsDeleted, FileOwner) "
    SQLString = SQLString & " values('" & path & "','" & DateTime.Parse(getCreationTime(path)) & "','" & DateTime.Parse(getModifiedTime(path)) & "'," & 0 & ",'" & getOwner(path).ToString & "')"
    Call ExecuteSQL(SQLString)
End Sub 'ProcessFile
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: Thanks to user rheitzman for reminding about bulk load. 
my solution ended up like this.

Get the files and folder onto a text file

```
dir > test.txt /b /s
```

Then use bulk load to insert text file into SQL table

```
BULK INSERT nProject FROM 'c:\test.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

This bulk load takes less than 40 minutes to process 2 million rows (from 10 hours to 40 minutes) I am happy. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depends a lot on want "analyze" means.

If you just want to find outsized files or folders I'd use a utility like BYSIZE http://www.semaphorecorp.com/bysize/bysize.html You have to run manually and save the results but it is about the fastest way I've seen for the task.

Another option is RoboCopy. Run a list (/L) only with the header/footer suppressed and you will get a tab separated file you can process. Check out all the switch options - http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html  (e.g Logging Options, /BYTES, /MIN.)  Doesn't roll up to directories as BySize does. You can bulk load the resulting file into SQL Server.

My guess is the slowest part of your OP code is the INSERT logic. Also, if you are doing numerous inserts transaction logging and caching can be a real issues. You could continue on your path but use stringbuilder and write tab separated data to disk every 10,000 records or so. Then bulk load the data into SQL Server.

With all options is the subject drive has the OS installed exclude the OS folders.

Comment: thanks for reminding about bulk load to SQL server. I need to analyze folder structure. as it is a specific drive that store company projects and each projects has to have a specific folder structure and specific files inside each folder. I have to check them, to see if there is typo in the folder name, or missing folder that should have been existed ect.

Comment: You may be able to remove some overhead - just scan for directories, check structure, and only drill into the folders you need to check. Depends on highly structure the disk storage is. This seems like the kind of task that could/should be performed at specific task times - that way you only have to check the folders for the specific task milestone.

Comment: I ended up just doing "dir > test.txt /b /s" this process takes 20 mins. Then I just use "BULK INSERT nProject FROM 'c:\test.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',ROWTERMINATOR  = '\n')" takes about 5 minutes. I got about 2 millions files and folders. I think I am happy with this.